# How do I start a SASS project in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sass, sublimetext2

I have all the correct packages installed and have SASS running. Now I just need to figure out how to start a project with it. Are there any pre-built templates that show you the file structure, etc...Any help would be great!

Comment: have you been through this: http://aspirecode.com/how-to-add-sass-support-in-sublime-text/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way would be to install Compass (http://compass-style.org/) and then it's a simple as running:

```
compass create project-name
```

Which would create the structure for you.

And then to compile

```
compass watch
```

More can be seen here http://thesassway.com/beginner/getting-started-with-sass-and-compass